# Capybara can't find anything to click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

This is driving me crazy. Capybara cannot find the link to click! The view is created from a Rails form helper that originally in the view code looks like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Go!", id: "submit-button" class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %>
```

Note that this snippet of code is in a partial `_form.html.erb` that is called by the `requests/new` page that the test is visiting (i.e., `new_request_path`). I initially thought this was a problem, but then I did a `save_and_open_page` using launchy, and the following code is from the Inspect Element, which clearly shows that the code is rendering fine.

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" name="commit" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Go!">
```

And yet this test keeps producing errors.

```
require 'spec_helper' #should have the right config; required capybara/rspec and capybara/rails, and included Capybara::DSL

describe "simple user flow" do

it "should carry form information to redirected edit page" do
    visit new_request_path
    fill_in('Email we will use to contact you', :with => "fake@gmail.com")
    # save_and_open_page  # this is what created the view snippet I've shown above
    # below are all the variations of clicking that i tried, none of which worked!
            click_link('Go!') #value
            click_link('submit-button') #id
            click_link('commit') #name
            click_link('btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block') #class
            click_link('submit') #type
            click_button('Go!') #value
            click_button('submit-button') #id
            click_button('commit') #name
            click_button('btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block') #class
            click_button('submit') #type
    expect(page).to have_content "fake@gmail.com"
    end

end
```

I'm forever stuck with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: click_link('commit')
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find link "commit"
```

FYI Spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering
  config.render_views
end
```

Comment: Post the contents of your spep_heper.rb. For sanity check here is mine: http://pastie.org/9286533

Comment: Ok I've added it above.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Bud'Mugur'Chirica honestly don't remember. At this point, all of my capybara clicks are done with `find(:css).click` because it's less flaky. But another thing that can confuse it; if you have content layered over the content that needs to be clicked that's just hidden (like... a pull out drawer or something), you may have to manually scroll down to the point where the click can occur

Comment: Thanks for the tips.